# How to abort File::Find::Rule after first match?

Tags: perl

I am using
[`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule)
in the following piece of code to search recursively for
a file within a given directory.

#### Perl code

```
my $WD = Cwd::abs_path();

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->relative()->name( '*.txt' )->in($WD);

for my $file ( @files ) {
    print "file: $file\n";
}
```

#### Directory structure

```
|--- DIR1
     |-- subdir1
             |-- *.txt
     |-- subdir2
             |-- *.txt
             |-- *.txt
```

#### Current output

```
DIR1/subdir1/*.txt
DIR1/subdir2/*.txt
DIR1/subdir2/*.txt
```

#### Desired output

```
DIR1/subdir1/*.txt
```

Can someone please suggest what can be done?

Comment: Why use `->in($WD)` instead of `->in('.')`?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use [its `exec`](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm#exec), in order to stop matching once the path of files found changes

```
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->relative->name('*.txt')
    ->exec( sub { 
        state $path = ''; 
        return 0 if $path and $path ne $_[1]; 
        $path = $_[1]; 
     }
)->in($WD);
```

The subroutine in `exec` is invoked once the files are found, and in it the path to files is available as the second argument in `@_`. Once that path changes from what it had been up to that point it means that the search has found files in a different directory.

As soon as that happens we stop changing `$path` so all further queries on that directory fail.

This is a simple way to detect change of directories in which files are found. Check by replacing `return 0` with, for example, `say "Changed from $path to $_[1]";`.

Tested as `perl -Mstrict -MFile::Find::Rule -wE'...'`, and `'` in code were `"`.

Note: you need `use feature 'state';` for [state](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) (unless you are under `use v5.10` or higher). In a one-liner the [`-E`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) (as opposed to `-e`) enables all [feature](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#The-%27state%27-feature)s, in the main compilation unit.

---

Early comments changed (or obscured) the requirement in the title to abort altogether under the stated condition. In that case `die` instead of `return 0`, inside `eval`

```
my @files;
eval { 
    @files = File::Find::Rule->file->relative->name('*>txt')
        ->exec( sub { 
            state $path = ''; 
            die "CHANGED_DIR\n" if $path and $path ne $_[1];
            $path = $_[1];
        })
        ->in($WD);
} or do { die $@ if $@ ne 'CHANGED_DIR' }
```

where the string for `die` is made up only so that we can check and re-throw if needed.

Comment: @Saurabh Updated the explanation and added a note on needed `use feature 'state'`

Comment: Thank you zdim !!